# python: what happens during easy_install?

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm a little confused about egg files and installing them using easy_install, hope you can help me with it. (I read about people's recommendation on pip, but I'll like to understand this before I move on).

If I simply copy e,g `django_guardian-1.0.2-py2.6.egg` from say, a thumbdrive  and place in e.g `~/bar/` which PYTHONPATH was pointing to, trying to import the contents via `import guardian` would yield me importError. This error occur even if I have the `easy_install.pth` copied in

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./django_guardian-1.0.2-py2.6.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys
'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

Now, using `easy_install django-guardian`, of course had no such problem.

I navigated to the directory the egg file was easy_installed to, and all it contains was the `.pth` and the `.egg` file. I wish to know what other procedures/entries does easy_install makes somewhere that makes the first method unusable....

Comment: Why would you copy an egg? Did not introduced yourself to `virtualenv` yet?

Comment: @Nemoden, yes i heard of virtualenv, but I am curious on why the above would not work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`easy_install` uses `.pth` files to add the `.egg` files to `sys.path` -- the list of locations where Python searches for modules to import.

`.pth` files are processed by the `site` module, but only in four pre-defined directories.  These directories are platform-specific and based on the `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix` settings.  On Unix, the most prominent usually is `/usr/lib/pythonXX/site-packages`.

Since your custom directory is not one of the directories processed by `site`, your `.pth` file won't get processed and Python won't look inside the `.egg`.

For more information, see [the `site` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html).